# Syncronous Container and Object in Svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I am working with svg.js and try to make an object run from A->B, then rotate 90 degree, and continue run.
But when rotate the object, it s also rotate the coordinate axis. So, i put that object into a container (draw.group())
But the object animate and the group animate work asynchronous.
This is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="drawing"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.6/svg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var draw = SVG('drawing')
        var group = draw.group()
        var circle= group.rect(50, 50)

        circle.animate(2000).rotate(90, 0, 0)    
        group.animate(2000).move(100, 100)
    </script>
</body>
```

So, i want the rect object rotate first, then move, not work in the same time.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback

```
circle.animate(2000).rotate(90, 0, 0).after(function() {
  group.animate(2000).move(100, 100)
})
```

http://svgjs.dev/animating/#callbacks

Comment: thanks, it worked. But is there any other solution, because i had many rotate and move actions and i dont want to handle callback hell